# ZeroDivisionError: division by zero error in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, divide-by-zero

I have got Zero division error from nowhere. I don't understand what is the reason for this error. I googled it but couldn't find the answer. In my GAE Log, I have the following text.

```
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6\jinja2\environment.py", line 894, in render

        return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)

      File "C:\NyBytt\nybytt-server\templates\admin.html", line 1, in top-level template code

        {% extends "abc.html" %}

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Anyone has ever experience this error?

Comment: The error is going to be in your `admin.html` or `abc.html`. Without being able to see those the help you receive will be minimal. Maybe add them to your question.

Comment: +1 - Please share your `abc.html` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed. The problem was in the template file. I must say, the google log is a bit confusing. The log indicating the error on line 1 i.e in abc.html while the error was in admin.html.